# Redirect to another page using angular

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I'm using a php server and angular. i'm trying to create a login page that on success redriect to another page using header(location: ...), on the client side i see in the network console i received the raw page header and a redirect request initilaized by the login.php to the requested page but nothing happens.
any suggestions?

Comment: `any suggestions`.. yes, post code and some routing details

Comment: are you using ajax? And in response, trying to redirect using PHP `header` function?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:
function () { $location.path('/URL'); }); 
Inside your login function, on success.